# Improving my SQL query with SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In the past year or so, I have been spending most of time working with noSQL databases. That said, I have started a new job that works with a SQL database and SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Any suggestions that would improve readability and make the query more concise would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [db1].[id] as "Node ID",
    [db2].[name] as "Node Name",
    [db3].[name] as "ISP",
    [db4].[name] as "City",
    CASE
       WHEN [db1].[object_type_id] = 17
          THEN 'Client'
       WHEN [db1].[synthetic_location].[object_type_id] = 5
          THEN 'System'
       WHEN [db1].[object_type_id] IS NULL
          THEN 'System'
    END AS Type
FROM 
    [db1].[synthetic_location]
JOIN 
    [db2].[machine] ON [db2].[synthetic_location_id] IS NULL
JOIN 
    [db3].[internet_service_provider] ON [db3].[id] = [db1].[internet_service_provider_id]
JOIN 
    [db4].[geography_city] ON [db4].[geography_city].[id] = [db1].[synthetic_location].[geography_city_id]
WHERE 
    [db2].[status_type_id] < 1
    AND [db1].[flags] = 6
```

Comment: What about it is not readable and not concise?

Comment: There does not seem to be a standard.  You see some really bad one.  This looks OK to me.   This question might get closed as you are only asking about style.

Comment: Your first join does not say what columns to join on like `db1.synthetic_location.column_name join db2.machine.column_name on db1.synthetic_location.column_name = db2.machine.coumn_name and db2.machine.column_name is null`

Comment: Off topic for SO.   This question should be on CodeReview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review.

Comment: Voting to close because OP did not fix the join

Comment: Sorry guys! This is the second time I have asked a question on StackOverflow! That said, I think this should be in CodeReview. I'll be certain to tag it correctly going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks fine and is perfectly readable with one exception;

You should explicitly state `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN` as it makes the intention clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like SSMS Boost or SQL complete that will help you to format the queries and those tools have so many additional features that can save lot of your time